# How to make multiple playback buttons?

Tags: javascript, html5-audio

I have code for one button, how to do for multiple?
[image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3sFz.jpg)

I tried to get around all the elements, but the tracks played simultaneously.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mmyaQx

On jquery I did it, but I can not on native JavaScript.

```js
window.onload = function(){

   var myAudio = document.getElementById('my-audio');
   var play = document.getElementById('play');
   var pause = document.getElementById('pause');
   var loading = document.getElementById('loading');
   var bar = document.getElementById('bar');

   function displayControls() {
      loading.style.display = "none";
      play.style.display = "block";
   }

   // check that the media is ready before displaying the controls
   if (myAudio.paused) {
      displayControls();
   } else {
      // not ready yet - wait for canplay event
      myAudio.addEventListener('canplay', function() {
         displayControls();
      });
   }
    
   play.addEventListener('click', function() {
      myAudio.play();
      play.style.display = "none";
      pause.style.display = "block";
   });
    
   pause.addEventListener('click', function() {
      myAudio.pause();
      pause.style.display = "none";
      play.style.display = "block";
   });
    
   // display progress
    
   myAudio.addEventListener('timeupdate', function() {
      //sets the percentage
      bar.style.width = parseInt(((myAudio.currentTime / myAudio.duration) * 100), 10) + "%";
   });

}
```

```css
#controls {
   width: 80px;
   float: left;
}
    
#progress {
   margin-left: 80px;
   border: 1px solid black;
}

#bar {
   height: 20px;
   background-color: green;
   width: 0;
}
```

```html
<audio id="my-audio">
  <source src="http://jPlayer.org/audio/mp3/Miaow-07-Bubble.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  <source src="http://jPlayer.org/audio/ogg/Miaow-07-Bubble.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
</audio>

<div id="controls">
  <span id="loading">loading</span>
  <button id="play" style="display:none">play</button>
  <button id="pause" style="display:none" >pause</button>
</div>
<div id="progress">
  <div id="bar"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what you want to achieve, but it seems that you are trying to reinvent the wheel...

Do you know that you can enable controls on the HTML5 audio player? :)

```html
<audio controls>
  <source src="http://jPlayer.org/audio/mp3/Miaow-07-Bubble.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  <source src="http://jPlayer.org/audio/ogg/Miaow-07-Bubble.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
</audio>
```

Comment: Yes I know. But I need a custom button.
On the page there are several play buttons that change on the pause. No more controls are needed.

Comment: Progress bar only for a visual example (suddenly someone without a sound), I also delete it.

Comment: @Massef "On the page there are several play buttons that change on the pause." What do you mean? Why do you need several play buttons?

Comment: The page has a catalog of tracks that you can listen to. Each track has only one button - play. You can also put on pause, the buttons are simply replaced show / hide.
If for example a certain track plays, and the user clicks on the play button on another track, the previous one stops.

Comment: http://dl3.joxi.net/drive/2017/04/15/0021/0106/1425514/14/979118a448.jpg

Comment: That's much clearer, thanks. If I were you, I would use a library like [howler.js](https://howlerjs.com/) to keep things clean and organized...

Answer (score 0):

something like this will help you..

make function instead of window.onload and paremetrize it.. then call each in start function..

```
function start(){
  buildOne( 'my-audio', 'play', 'pause', 'loading', 'bar' );
  buildOne( 'my-audio2', 'play2', 'pause2', 'loading2', 'bar2' );
}

window.onload = start;
```

full example is here: http://codepen.io/mkdizajn/pen/ZKYwEQ?editors=1011

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The number of elements on the page is not always the same. This option is not suitable. I tried to make class instead of id and go through the click method (like method each in jquery), but it did not work out.